# Selenium:Cant click on radio button,check box

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm new to selenium. I was trying to select radio button from a form. It has id. `By.id("test12")).getAttribute("value"))`, displays the correct value,but if i do `By.id("test12")).click();` did not click the element.
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='test13']")).getAttribute("Value"));`
also displays the name. but `click()` didn't work.

> I got org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   Command duration or timeout: 30.09 seconds

`<input id="test12" class="with-gap" type="radio" value="P" name="group1">`
`<input id="test13" class="with-gap" type="radio" value="C" name="group1">`

```
    List<WebElement> eRB=driver.findElements(By.name("group1"));
    System.out.println(eRB.size());
    for(int i=0;i<eRB.size();i++)
    {
       System.out.println(eRB.get(i).getAttribute("id")+" is Displayed = "+eRB.get(i).isDisplayed());
    }
```

the o/p was:

```
4
test13 false
test12 false
test13 false
test12 false
```

Could anyone tell what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share website?

Comment: Try to replace isDisplayed with something else, this method may not work on checkbox and radiobox.

Comment: Please share your html code.

Comment: @Kishan Patel Website is :https://www.jobsforher.com/employer/account/sign_up

Answer (score 0):

@Suba Narayanan, use webdriver wait to check the visibility of the element before clicking.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("test12"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for clicking the radio button:

```
driver.get("https://www.jobsforher.com/employer/account/sign_up");
Thread.sleep(5000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='test2']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/label")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

You can customise your wait by waiting for specific element.
Let me know for more queries.
Happy Learning. :)